# How did they simplify this expression involving roots of unity?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers

Suppose $\omega$ is a primitive seventh root of unity.  I would like to find as simple an expression as possible for $$ \sum_{j=0}^6 (1 + \omega^j)^n. $$

The book I am looking at gives 
$$ 2^n \left\lfloor 1+2\sum_{j=1}^3 \cos{\frac{\pi j n}{7}} \cos^n \frac{ \pi j}{j} \right\rfloor $$
with no explanation, and I am wondering how they got this.  (I am also wondering if it is a typo, since this book seems to have quite a few --- if it is correct as written, why not cancel the rightmost $j$'s and rewrite $\cos^n \pi$ as $(-1)^n$?)

**Added:**

Motivation: this is the last step in simplifying the expression $$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n / 7 \rfloor} {n \choose 7k}.$$ This is problem #42(f) in section 1 of *Lovasz's Combinatorial Problems and Exercises, Second Edition*.  In my copy, the problem is on p. 21, and the solution (which makes sense until the last step) is on p. 195.

(To be clear, I have pulled out a factor of $\frac{1}{7}$ which appears somewhere along the way but is irrelevant to the above.)

Comment: For $n=1$ and $\omega=e^{i\pi/7}$, the top is +7 whereas the bottom is -6, there's got to be a typo. (Also, sometimes books don't cancel things right away to be more suggestive i.e. help the reader figure out how an expression was obtained.)

Comment: Also, just for fun (when $\omega$ is primitive): $$\sum_{j=0}^6(1+\omega^j)^n=\sum_{j=0}^6\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\omega^{kj} =\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\sum_{j=0}^6\omega^{kj}=\sum_{0\le7k\le n}{n\choose 7k}$$

Comment: anon, (1) $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / 7}$ would be a primitive seventh root of unity rather than $e^{\pi i /7}$, and (2) very nice, in fact   $$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{7} \rfloor} {n \choose 7k}$$ is exactly the expression we are trying to simplify!  This is supposed to be the last step.

Comment: @anon: that is a much nicer formula, although more terms. However, I believe that it needs an extra factor of 7 in the rightmost term.

Comment: Nevertheless, there seems to be an error in there somewhere. For $n=14$ the cosines are all $1$, so the bottom is just $7\cdot2^n$, whereas there's cancellation in the top so the upper bound $7\cdot2^n$ can't be attained.

Comment: Yes, I meant to write $e^{2\pi i/7}$ in my comment, but the result for $n=1$ is +7 so long as $\omega\ne1$ anyway. Could you provide more context, like book and page number, or maybe some of the other words that were written around the two given expressions? Would a proof the identity that doesn't involve the oddball cosine formula suffice for your purposes? @robjohn: Yes you are correct, I forgot there wasn't any normalization. There should be a 7 in front of the last summation in my comment.

Comment: I don't find the cosine formula oddball (other than it is incorrect as written!).  The point is that we have replaced the sum of $n / 7$ binomial coefficients where $n$ could be arbitrarily large, with a sum of only three terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is rather less mysterious than it looks and just resulted from a combination of two misprints. The floor function should be a bracket, and the $j$ in the denominator should be a $7$. Then the derivation is straightforward:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^6 \left(1 + \omega^j\right)^n
&=
\sum_{j=0}^6 \left(1 + \mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm ij/7}\right)^n
\\
&=
\sum_{j=0}^6 \left(\mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm ij/7}\left(\mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm ij/7}+\mathrm e^{-\pi\mathrm ij/7}\right)\right)^n
\\
&=
\sum_{j=0}^6 \mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm ijn/7}\left(2\cos\frac{\pi j}7\right)^n
\\
&=
2^n\sum_{j=0}^6 \mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm ijn/7}\cos^n\frac{\pi j}7
\\
&=
2^n\left(1+2\sum_{j=1}^3 \cos\frac{\pi jn}7\cos^n\frac{\pi j}7\right)\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I didn't mention the misprints, but I got the same answer. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn: Well, you didn't mention the misprints, but you mentioned the signs, which I deftly ignored :-)

Answer (score 5):

Using $1+e^{2\pi i/7\;j}=2\cos\left(\pi/7\;j\right)e^{\pi i/7\;j}$, we get
$$
\sum_{j=0}^6(1+\omega^j)^n=2^n\sum_{j=0}^6\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi j}{7}\right)e^{\pi i/7\;nj}\tag{1}
$$
Noting that each term in the sum can be paired with its conjugate, we see that the sum is real.  Therefore, we can simply take the real part of $(1)$, which yields
$$
\sum_{j=0}^6(1+\omega^j)^n=2^n\sum_{j=0}^6\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi j}{7}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi nj}{7}\right)\tag{2}
$$
Using that $\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi(7-j)}{7}\right)=(-1)^n\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi j}{7}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{\pi n(7-j)}{7}\right)=(-1)^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi nj}{7}\right)$ and $\cos(0)=1$, $(2)$ becomes
$$
\sum_{j=0}^6(1+\omega^j)^n=2^n\left[1+2\sum_{j=1}^3\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi j}{7}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi nj}{7}\right)\right]\tag{3}
$$

Comment: There is no way when looking at $(3)$ to see that it is an integer $=0\pmod{7}$, which is extremely clear from @anon's comment to the question.